# Cannot get .js to be called upon form POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bit of code that's "working," but is not doing what I want it to do.

On my page, I have a bit of code in the header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="update.js"></script>
```

and inside my main page, I have:

```
<form id="updateChanges" method="POST" action="update.php">
...code...
</form>
```

When I click the button inside of this form, I want the code inside of update.js to execute, but the page redirects to update.php and executes my code successfully instead.  I am trying to bypass this redirect, and execute the code without doing a page refresh.  I do not understand why it's not working.

I got the .js from a tutorial on how to use AJAX.

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#updateChanges');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(event) {

    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
});
});
```

my javascript file is not being called.  Why?

Comment: First thing first: Why two versions of jQuery?

Comment: From here: `https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery` it lists two.. so I copied both in.

Comment: Well, decide which version you want to use and use it.

Comment: Okay, going with 1.11.1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already defined jQuery form object in the `form` variable, you do not need to wrap it for jQuery again.

All instances of `$(form)` become: `form`

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#updateChanges');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    form.submit(function(event) {

        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = form.serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: formData
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay - I had wondered why it was like that in the tutorial as well....  I tried it both ways, and neither one works.  Is there a way for me to tell whether or not this javascript file is even being called?  I tried putting an `alert("hi");` at the top of the file but I got an error in the console.

Comment: Could you let us know what the error is? I think there is a bug somewhere further up in your code (or an included .js file) that is preventing this from being processed.

Comment: I can't seem to recreate it now - I just tried adding an alert and a `console.log()` into the .js file, but neither the alert nor the log shows up when I click my update button.  It seems that the file is being bypassed entirely because the page goes to update.php and executes what it's supposed to.

Comment: @lordterrin just updated the code above: it was missing one closing `});` block, which may be the root of your problems. It seems like it's being bypassed entirely because JavaScript only executes when NO errors occur.. which means one small error can stop processing all other JavaScript on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the fix!  The code is still not launching though.  I must be doing something wrong still.

Comment: Okay - I'm confused now.  I actually load (prior to any of this) another page, test.php.  It is from THAT page that I load getuser.php after selecting something from a drop-down menu.  If I go to test.php, and load getuser.php through the drop-down, this javascript function is NOT called.  However, if I go directly go getuser.php?q=John%20Doe, the script loads just fine.  Why is this?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @lordterrin very peculiar! Can we see the test.php/getuser.php contents? Specifically any JavaScript contents, or PHP that refers to $_GET or $_POST variables? I suspect there's something in there that needs tweaking... might be easier to post a new question & link to it from here

Comment: I've added the new post here:  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614053/php-and-js-in-multi-page-environment>